# Radio button with same id in Laravel 4.1.x

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
<div class="form-group  {{ (isset($errors) AND $errors->has('indicacao_interna')) ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
  {{ Form::label('indicacao_interna', 'Indicação Interna', array('class' => 'col-lg-4 control-label')) }}
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div>

      <label class='radio-inline'>{{ Form::radio('indicacao_interna', 1, oldRadio('indicacao_interna', 1, true)) }} Sim</label>
      <label class='radio-inline'>{{ Form::radio('indicacao_interna', 0, oldRadio('indicacao_interna', 0, true)) }} Não</label>
      @include('partials.validators.message_field', array('field' => 'indicacao_interna'))
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And it generates this code:

```
<div class="form-group  ">
  <label for="indicacao_interna" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Indicação Interna</label>                <div class="col-lg-3">
  <div>

    <label class="radio-inline"><input checked="checked" name="indicacao_interna" type="radio" value="1" id="indicacao_interna"> Sim</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input name="indicacao_interna" type="radio" value="0" id="indicacao_interna"> Não</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the radio button have the **same id**. This is wrong, right?

And... why the radio generate same id? Not just a name?

---

- Laravel 4.1
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 5.4.17

---

*Sorry for my english... thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's a small drawkback of automatic code creation. Behind the scenes, `Form::radio()` calls the same `$this->input($type, $name, $value = null, $options = array())` general function for the inputs, which inside calls:

```
$id = $this->getIdAttribute($name, $options);
```

The method `getIdAttribute()` has this definition:

```
public function getIdAttribute($name, $attributes)
{
    if (array_key_exists('id', $attributes))
    {
        return $attributes['id'];
    }

    if (in_array($name, $this->labels))
    {
        return $name;
    }
}
```

That means, if it finds a specified ID in the options provided it returns that, else it returns the name.

Which is a comfortable and perfectly valid solution for the other input types, but doesn't work well for radios and checkboxes, where you need to provide your own id.

```
{{ Form::radio('indicacao_interna', 1, oldRadio('indicacao_interna', 1, true),
    array('id' => 'custom_id')) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim:

```
{{ Form::radio('indicacao_interna', 1, oldRadio('indicacao_interna', 1, true),
    array('id' => 'indicacao_interna_1')) }}

{{ Form::radio('indicacao_interna', 1, oldRadio('indicacao_interna', 1, true), 
    array('id' => 'indicacao_interna_2')) }}
```

Comment: Quanto a isso ok. Mas na realidade ele deveria gerar os elementos sem id, e não com id e ainda sim iguais.

Comment: Pois é o Laravel não faz isso, uma solução é usar esse package que utilizo em meus projetos: https://github.com/Anahkiasen/former

Talvez abrir um issue no projeto do laravel. abraços!